# Haskell 99 Questions #27

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I'm having trouble conceptualizing given answer for problem 27 in haskell's 99 problems `https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/Solutions/27`.

The Problem:
"
Group the elements of a set into disjoint subsets.

a) In how many ways can a group of 9 people work in 3 disjoint subgroups of 2, 3 and 4 persons? Write a function that generates all the possibilities and returns them in a list.

Example:

```
* (group3 '(aldo beat carla david evi flip gary hugo ida))
( ( (ALDO BEAT) (CARLA DAVID EVI) (FLIP GARY HUGO IDA) )
... )
```

b) Generalize the above predicate in a way that we can specify a list of group sizes and the predicate will return a list of groups.
"

The answer they give is this:

```
combination :: Int -> [a] -> [([a],[a])]
combination 0 xs     = [([],xs)]
combination n []     = []
combination n (x:xs) = ts ++ ds
  where
    ts = [ (x:ys,zs) | (ys,zs) <- combination (n-1) xs ]
    ds = [ (ys,x:zs) | (ys,zs) <- combination  n    xs ]


group :: [Int] -> [a] -> [[[a]]]
group [] _ = [[]]
group (n:ns) xs =
    [ g:gs | (g,rs) <- combination n xs
           ,  gs    <- group ns rs ]
```

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how the first section (the section defining the function "combination") operates. 
I'm pretty new to haskell too, so explain it to me like I'm in 5th grade.

Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
combination 0 xs     = [([],xs)]
```

If we want to choose 0 elements from `xs`, there is only one way. No elements are taken `[]` and all the elements `xs` are left there.

```
combination n []     = []
```

Otherwise, we want to choose `n` (>0) elements. If we want to chose them from the empty list `[]`, there are no ways to do that -- it's impossible.

```
combination n (x:xs) = ts ++ ds
  where
    ts = [ (x:ys,zs) | (ys,zs) <- combination (n-1) xs ]
    ds = [ (ys,x:zs) | (ys,zs) <- combination  n    xs ]
```

Otherwise, we want to choose `n` (>0) elements from a nonempty list `x:xs`. There are many ways to do that, which we separate in two groups as follows:

- we decide to *take* the element `x` among the chosen ones, and we are left with choosing `n-1` from `xs`. This is done in `ts`, which considers all the ways to choose `n-1` elements from `xs`, and then adds `x` to the list of "chosen" elements `ys`.
- we decide to *drop* the element `x` from the input list, and we are left with choosing `n` from `xs`. This is done in `ds`, which considers all the ways to choose `n` elements from `xs`, and then adds `x` to the list of "dropped" elements `zs`.

We then output all such combinations using `ts++ds`.

Answer (score 0):

Function combination takes list and one number.  It creates the combination of the list considering the list has to be divided only in two parts. This is simply the original problem reduced only with 2 numbers k and n-k.

It does this using ts and ds lists.

ts is when the first element is in first part and then recursion occurs with remaining list and k-1. ds is where first element is in second part and recursion occurs with k and remaining part. Once remaining part is computed first element is added to it.